# How to pull the current user's email and insert into a script placeholder?

Tags: php

I am using an affiliate tracker called Rewardful, and it requires me to pass the users email to this script

```
<script>
rewardful('convert', { email: 'email@goeshere.com' })
</script>
```

The rewardful script is third party hosted by them, so I cannot modify this.

I have found some script to pull/echo the current user's email but I cannot figure out how to insert it into the placeholder of another script.

I have no idea if this matters in terms of how this question is answered, but this script will only be used on one page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to provide some additional context - most notably how does the script get into the page to begin with?  Is it via plugin?  Or perhaps something you hardcoded into the template?

Comment: how are you handling consent? What you're describing would be a data breach in EU countries and many US states unless the user opts in to this before you call the rewardful script

Comment: @TomJNowell I don't quite understand how I'm breaching any data by doing this

Comment: you're doing it by sending personally identifiable information to a 3rd party ( Rewardful ) without first gaining the consent of the user, there are regulations that cover this quite clearly, if you want to send users personal information offsite you have to ask the user for consent first. In the EU the GDPR regulations are what implement this, lots of other countries and states have similar regulations e.g. the California consumer privacy act, your own state has specific regulations around anything related to personal health or medical data via TMRPA

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you for the reply, I will look into that. i've just now signed up for it but from what I can tell, the only emails that are sent off site are the people that have signed up for my affiliate program, which also gives consent. the rewardful script is only checking the users information in the stripe userbase via webhooks, and it only does so after the user has checked out with stripe, thus voluntarily providing their email before any checks are done.

thank you for the heads up, I will triple check that i'm not missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any information on how you're getting the script on the page to begin with.  Assuming that this is something you have hardcoded into your template, here is a way you could approach it.

First, you need to check if the user is logged in, because if they are not, there's no point in outputting anything since you wouldn't have any data.

Next, use `wp_get_current_user()` to get the current user's info in a standard WP user object.  The user's email address will be in that object as `$user->user_email`.

Here's what that looks like in practice:

```
<?php
// Is the user logged in?
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
     // Get the current user.
     $user = wp_get_current_user();
     // Output your script.
     ?><script>
          rewardful('convert', { email: '<?php echo $user->user_email; ?>' })
     </script><?php
} ?>
```

Comment: @butterblog apologies, I wasn't aware that sharing that information would be helpful. and yes, just above where this new script will go I've enqueued the script in my functions.php file. I'll give this a go right now and see if it works...I'm sure it will. Thank you very much for the reply.